How does one pay off flaws?
The description of the Sterile merit in M20 Book Of Secrets reads as such:

For some physical reason, you’re unable to sire or conceive
children. Whether this is a Merit or a Flaw depends
upon whether or not you want to sire or conceive children.
Generally, this sort of condition can be easily cured with a
little Life-Sphere magick; in your case, though, it can’t be
rectified until and unless you, the player, discard the Merit
or pay off this Flaw.

But there are no mechanics provided for paying off flaws. Are there any such mechanics in another book and if so what are they?

I am not familiar with the 20th anniversary rules, but in prior editions, you either had to have the Storyteller give you freebie points that you could use for Merits or to buy off Flaws, or you had to discard a corresponding amount of Merits.

Storyteller fiat and experience point expenditure.
On page 642 of the 20th Anniversary Edition Core rules for Mage: The Ascension, it reads:

Generally, Merits and Flaws cannot be purchased after character
creation, although the Storyteller may decide to give them to
characters in place of experience points if those Traits seem
appropriate to the events within the chronicle. Depending upon those
events, a player might be able to use experience points to buy off a
troublesome Flaw. In all cases, Merits and Flaws are optional Traits.
The Storyteller may disallow some, all, or none of them – it’s her
choice.

And then, on page 645, we find:

Flaws offer extra freebie points during character creation. Even so,
they’re not only point-magnets; each Flaw presents a story-based
challenge that must be faced and overcome throughout a character’s
life. Until and unless that Flaw gets bought off with experience
points and some significant events within the chronicle, a Flaw
remains a monumental pain in the ass for a mage, his companions, and
the player who decides to take it.

So, you need the ST's permission, an in-fiction trigger, and a spend of XP. How many XP? That question isn't answered in the experience point tables in M20; check with your storyteller.

Anecdotally, it's somewhat common to treat Flaws (and even Merits) as Backgrounds in terms of XP cost, if XP cost is needed. This would be a current rating * 3. I've also seen other costs assigned, but this is quite close to the average.
